Laravel-excel export not downloading instead its just storing
I have this laravel project where i added this package laravel-excel to export data from database now instead of downloading it is saving to this directory storage\framework\cache\laravel-excel
this is my vue code
<script setup>

import { router} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { ref } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({transactions:Object});

const status =ref('Status');
const shop =ref('Shop');

const handleExport = ()=>{
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('status', status.value);
    formData.append('shop', shop.value);
   
    router.post('/export_data', formData,{
         preserveState: true, preserveScroll: true,
    })
}
</script>

<template>
    <button @click="handleExport()" type="button"></button>
</template>

here is my controller code
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Exports\TransactionsExport;
use App\Models\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class TransactionController extends Controller
{
    public function export_data(Request $request)
    {
        $status =  $request['status'];
        $shop = $request['shop'];
        
        $result =  Transaction::where([['status',$status],['shop',$shop]])->get();
        return Excel::download(new TransactionsExport($result), 'Transactions.xlsx');
    }
}

additional information, am getting the right data but again instead of downloading its just saving.
thanks

It looks like the response generated by Excel::download is not being handled correctly on the frontend, which is causing it to be saved to the server's cache instead of prompting a file download on the client.
Here’s how to solve it:
Use Inertia::post instead of router.post for download: Since you want the file to download directly and not go through Inertia’s SPA-like behavior, a typical Inertia post request will not work as expected. Instead, make a direct GET request from the client.
Update the Vue Code to Trigger a GET Request: Change the handleExport function to open the download link directly in the browser using window.location.
Revised Code
Vue Component (handleExport function)
Update the handleExport function to construct a URL with query parameters and initiate a download request:
import { ref } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({ transactions: Object });

const status = ref('Status');
const shop = ref('Shop');

const handleExport = () => {
    // Construct a query string for GET request with parameters
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
        status: status.value,
        shop: shop.value
    }).toString();

    // Redirect to the URL which triggers the download
    window.location.href = `/export_data?${params}`;
};


<template>
    <button @click="handleExport" type="button">Export Data</button>
</template>

Controller (export_data function)
Change the export_data method to accept the parameters as a GET request:
    public function export_data(Request $request)
{
    $status = $request->query('status');  // Use query parameters
    $shop = $request->query('shop');

    // Retrieve the filtered data
    $result = Transaction::where([['status', $status], ['shop', $shop]])->get();

    // Export and download the data
    return Excel::download(new TransactionsExport($result), 'Transactions.xlsx');
}

